# JsonRest in Dojo Widget, no method query()

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo

I'm building a templated widget in which I create a form with a ComboBox inside which I try to fill with a JsonRest

This is the code I use for the widget:

```
define( [ 
  'dojo/_base/declare', 
  'dijit/_WidgetBase', 
  'dijit/_TemplatedMixin', 
  'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin', 
  'dojo/text!./templates/PanelDesigner.html', 
  'dijit/form/TextBox', 
  'dijit/form/Form', 
  'dojo/store/JsonRest', 
  'dijit/form/ComboBox' 
], 

  function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template,   JsonRest) { 
    worksector_store = new JsonRest({ 
      target: '/worksectors' 
    }); 

  return declare('ppc.panel_designer.PanelDesigner',[_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], { 
    templateString: template, 
    widgetsInTemplate: true 
  }); 
});
```

And this is the template being loaded:

```
<div id='${baseClass}' data-dojo-type='dijit/form/Form' data-dojo-id='${baseClass}'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for:'name'>Name:</label></td>
      <td><input type='text' id='name' name='name' required='true' data-dojo-type='dijit/form/TextBox'/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label for:'worksector'>Worksector:</label></td>
      <td><input id='worksector' name='worksector' data-dojo-type='dijit/form/ComboBox' data-dojo-props="store:worksector_store" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But when I try to use the ComboBox I always get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [Widget dijit.form.TextBox, dijit_form_TextBox_0] has no method 'query'
```

I have been searching for some time now but haven't found the solution yet. I tried to remove the store from the template and call the query method directly in a postCreate method in the declare function but that gives me the same error.

Thanks in advance. 
Marcel

## Solution:

The problem was how I the order of the arguments of the function passed to define. The first argument is a array of objects to include and the second is a function with a list of variables.

The order of the variables in the function need to be the same as the order of the objects in the passed array.

So the code of the widget now looks like:

```
define( [
  'dojo/_base/declare',
  'dijit/_WidgetBase',
  'dijit/_TemplatedMixin',
  'dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin',
  'dojo/text!./templates/PanelDesigner.html',
  'dojo/store/JsonRest',
  'dojo/store/Memory',
  'dijit/form/ComboBox',
  'dijit/form/Form',
  'dijit/form/TextBox'
],
function(declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, template, JsonRest, Memory, ComboBox) {
  worksector_store = new JsonRest({
    target: '/worksectors'
  });

  return declare('ppc.panel_designer.PanelDesigner',[_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin,     _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
    templateString: template,
    widgetsInTemplate: true,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `worksector_store` variable is visible within the template.  I  think you'll want to just create the ComboBox declaratively:

```
define([..],function(..){
  var worksector_store = new JsonRest({});

  return declare('...',[deps],{
    buildRendering:function(){
      //do the other templated dom building
      this.inherited(arguments);
      this.comboBox = new CombBox({store:worksector_store});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I did a quick test, if I do the `var worksector_store = ...` and do `postCreate: function() { console.log(worksector_store.query(); }` in the declare I still get the same error.